# Exibir trecho de texto baseado em condicional com regex

Tags: php, regex

Estou tentando criar um "gerador" de texto dinâmico que irá substituir padrões com dados de um array usando regex, a estrutura é a seguinte:

> Olá, [usuario], seu cadastro foi efetuado em [data_cadastro]
> {aceitou_termos=sim} ,e você ganhou 1 milhão de reais {aceitou_termos},
> seu primeiro nome é [usuario,1] {assinante=nao} assine hoje e ganha 10% de desconto{assinante}

onde `{aceitou_termos=sim} TEXTO {aceitou_termos}` e `{assinante=nao} TEXTO {assinante}` seriam condições para exibição dependendo unicamente dos valores correspondentes no array.

exemplo:

```
$array['aceitou_termos'] = 'sim';
$array['assinante'] = 'nao';
```

O texto resultado seria:

> Olá, [usuario], seu cadastro foi efetuado em [data_cadastro],e você
> ganhou 1 milhão de reais ,seu primeiro nome é [usuario,1] assine hoje
> e ganha 10% de desconto

Eu até consigo capturar o que fica dentro do array, mas como posso exibir ou remover todo o "conjunto" baseado no valor proveniente do array usando regex?

Comment: atualizei a pergunta, na verdade é pra exibir o texto dependendo da condição, ele pode exibir tanto com "sim" ou "nao"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ideia é primeiro verificar se a tag possui o mesmo valor do array, e fazer a substituição de acordo.

Se o valor é o mesmo do array, eu removo somente as tags e mantenho o texto entre elas. Senão, eu removo tudo (as tags e o texto):

```
function remove($texto, $array, $tag) {
    $opcao = $array[$tag];
    // se a tag tem o mesmo valor do array
    if (preg_match("/\{$tag=$opcao\}/", $texto)) {
        $replace = '$1'; // substitui pelo texto entre as tags
    } else { // senão, remove tudo
        $replace = '';
        $opcao = '[^}]+';
    }
    $regex = "/\{$tag=$opcao\}([^{]+)\{$tag\}/";
    return preg_replace($regex, $replace, $texto);
}

$texto = 'Olá, [usuario], seu cadastro foi efetuado em [data_cadastro] {aceitou_termos=sim} ,e você ganhou 1 milhão de reais {aceitou_termos}, seu primeiro nome é [usuario,1] {assinante=nao} assine hoje e ganha 10% de desconto{assinante}';

$array['aceitou_termos'] = 'sim';
$array['assinante'] = 'nao';

$textoFinal = remove($texto, $array, 'aceitou_termos');
$textoFinal = remove($textoFinal, $array, 'assinante');
```

Ou seja, se tiver a tag com o mesmo valor do array, eu faço a substituição pelo texto entre as tags. Para isso eu uso `[^{]+` (um ou mais caracteres que não sejam `{`). Ou seja, estou assumindo que o texto entre as tags não tem nenhum `{`.

No caso de manter o texto, eu coloco o trecho `[^{]+` entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](http://regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), assim consigo obter o seu conteúdo depois, com `$1`.

Se a tag não tem o mesmo valor, eu removo tudo (faço o `replace` pela string vazia).

---

Se o array contém somente as tags e seus respectivos valores, também pode ser feito um *loop* por elas, e ir trocando todas:

```
function remove($texto, $array, $tag, $opcao) {
    if (preg_match("/\{$tag=$opcao\}/", $texto)) {
        $replace = '$1';
    } else {
        $replace = '';
        $opcao = '[^}]+';
    }
    $regex = "/\{$tag=$opcao\}([^{]+)\{$tag\}/";
    return preg_replace($regex, $replace, $texto);
}

$texto = 'Olá, [usuario], seu cadastro foi efetuado em [data_cadastro] {aceitou_termos=sim} ,e você ganhou 1 milhão de reais {aceitou_termos}, seu primeiro nome é [usuario,1] {assinante=nao} assine hoje e ganha 10% de desconto{assinante}. {obs=sim}Obs: etc blabla{obs}';

$array = [
    'aceitou_termos' => 'sim',
    'assinante' => 'nao',
    'obs' => 'sim'
];
$textoFinal = $texto;
foreach ($array as $tag => $opcao) {
    $textoFinal = remove($textoFinal, $array, $tag, $opcao);
}

echo $textoFinal;
```

---

Se as tags existirem mais de uma vez no texto, aí é um pouco mais chato (e ineficiente, talvez seja melhor [usar/construir um *parser* ou algo assim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440480/how-to-write-an-antlr-parser-for-jsp-asp-php-like-languages)), pois você tem que verificar cada ocorrência da tag, verificar se o valor é igual ao do array e fazer a substituição:

```
function remove($texto, $array, $tag, $opcao) {
    while (preg_match("/\{$tag=([^}]+)\}/", $texto, $matches)) {
        if ($matches[1] == $opcao) {
            $replace = '$1';
            $opt = $opcao;
        } else {
            $replace = '';
            $opt = '[^}]+';
        }
        $regex = "/\{$tag=$opt\}([^{]+)\{$tag\}/";
        $texto = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $texto, 1);
    }
    return $texto;
}

$texto = 'Olá {aceitou_termos=sim}aceitou termos {aceitou_termos}bla bla etc {assinante=nao}não assinou{assinante} xyz{aceitou_termos=nao} não aceitou{aceitou_termos}.';

$array = [
    'aceitou_termos' => 'sim',
    'assinante' => 'nao'
];
$textoFinal = $texto;
foreach ($array as $tag => $opcao) {
    $textoFinal = remove($textoFinal, $array, $tag, $opcao);
}

echo $textoFinal;
```

Ou seja, enquanto tiver a tag, verifica se o valor é igual ao do array e faz a substituição de acordo (ou remove tudo, ou mantém o texto entre as tags).

No caso, se `aceitou_termos` for "sim", o resultado será:

```
Olá aceitou termos bla bla etc não assinou xyz.
```

E se `aceitou_termos` for "nao", o resultado será:

```
Olá bla bla etc não assinou xyz não aceitou.
```

---

> O restante da resposta abaixo é para a [primeira versão da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/474682/1), que acho que pode ser útil a quem interessar.

Não acho que precise de regex. Se só tiver uma ocorrência da "tag" `{aceitou_termos}`, dá para fazer apenas com [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) e [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$texto = 'Olá, [usuario], seu cadastro foi efetuado em [data_cadastro]{aceitou_termos}, e você ganhou 1 milhão de reais {aceitou_termos}, seu primeiro nome é [usuario,1]';
$array['aceitou_termos'] = 'sim';

$tag = '{aceitou_termos}';
$len = strlen($tag);
$inicioTag = strpos($texto, $tag); // primeira ocorrência da tag
$fimTag = strpos($texto, $tag, $inicioTag + $len); // segunda ocorrência da tag

$textoFinal = substr($texto, 0, $inicioTag);  // pega do início até a primeira ocorrência da tag
if ($array['aceitou_termos'] == 'sim') { // pega o texto entre as tags
    $textoFinal .= substr($texto, $inicioTag + $len, $fimTag - $inicioTag - $len);
}
$textoFinal .= substr($texto, $fimTag + $len); // pega da segunda ocorrência da tag até o final da string
echo $textoFinal;
```

Ou seja, eu pego as posições da primeira e última ocorrência da tag, e vejo se o que está entre elas deve ser concatenado ou não.

---

Mas claro que dá para fazer com regex:

```
$texto = 'Olá, [usuario], seu cadastro foi efetuado em [data_cadastro]{aceitou_termos}, e você ganhou 1 milhão de reais {aceitou_termos}, seu primeiro nome é [usuario,1]';
if ($array['aceitou_termos'] == 'sim') {
    // sim, basta remover as tags
    $textoFinal = str_replace('{aceitou_termos}', '', $texto);
} else {
    // remove as tags e o texto entre elas
    $textoFinal = preg_replace('/\{aceitou_termos\}[^{]+\{aceitou_termos\}/', '', $texto);
}
echo $textoFinal;
```

Apesar de ter menos linhas, será que ficou mais simples? É relativo, mas de qualquer forma, a ideia é pegar as próprias tags (e os colchetes devem ser escapados com `\`), e entre eles eu uso `[^{]+` (um ou mais caracteres que não sejam `{`). Ou seja, estou assumindo que o texto entre as tags não tem nenhum `{`.

Repare que se tiver que incluir o texto entre as tags, basta remover as próprias tags, usando um *replace* simples (sem regex).

---

Já para o segundo caso, ficaria assim:

```
// se for "nao", remove tudo entre as tags
$textoFinal = preg_replace('/\{aceitou_termos=nao\}[^{]+\{aceitou_termos\}/', '', $texto);
// se for "sim", mantém o texto entre as tags
$textoFinal = preg_replace('/\{aceitou_termos=sim\}([^{]+)\{aceitou_termos\}/', '$1', $textoFinal);
```

A descrição da pergunta me parece que está ao contrário, pois diz que deve exibir o texto se for `{aceitou_termos=nao}`, mas entendo que o texto só deve ser exibido se for `{aceitou_termos=sim}` (mas se não for isso, basta inverter o "sim" e o "nao" no código acima).

No caso de manter o texto, eu coloco o trecho `[^{]+` entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](http://regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), assim consigo obter o seu conteúdo depois, com `$1`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas precisei atualizar a pergunta pois faltou um detalhe, o texto pode ser exibido dependendo do valor, podendo ser sim ou não {aceitou_termos=sim|nao}

Comment: @NBAYoungCoder Atualizei a resposta

Comment: perdão, havia me expressado mal, atualizei a pergunta novamente para ficar mais claro

Comment: @NBAYoungCoder Atualizei de novo..

Comment: Obrigado, como posso fazer com que funciona se existirem várias condições com as mesmas tags? se eu usar 2 assinates, um igual a "sim" e outro igual a "nao", não funciona e ele é exibido

Comment: @NBAYoungCoder Atualizei mais uma vez a resposta. Como dica, sugiro que sempre tente colocar exemplos mais próximos do real, assim evita esse "vai e vem" de informações. Para mim não tinha ficado claro se a mesma tag podia se repetir (claro que era uma possibilidade, mas acabei não considerando na resposta por "preguiça") :-)

Comment: Entendo, muito obrigado!